# 'kotlin-android-extensions' is no longer supported even though not using

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gradle, detox

Since the weekend assembling a release with `./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace` won't work any longer 
We get the following error even though we are not using either 'kotlin-android-extensions' or 'parcelize'

```
> Task :detox:compileCoreNativeReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: The Android extensions ('kotlin-android-extensions') compiler plugin is no longer supported. Please use kotlin parcelize and view binding. More information: https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation
```